# Android async rest web request design

Tags: android, web-services, web

I am new to Android dev and have the following design question when one makes an asnyc rest web request. In my main activity I have a button that does the request using an async task:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

final Context context=this;
.......

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myshowbutton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            WebRequest wr=new WebRequest(view.getRootView());
            wr.execute("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese?level=1");
        }
    });
}
```

Th async task class which is in a separate java file:

```
public class WebRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private View view;
public WebRequest(View v) {
   this.view = v;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    String responseString = null;
    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(uri[0]));
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            responseString = out.toString();
        } else{
            //Closes the connection.
            response.getEntity().getContent().close();
            throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //TODO Handle problems..
    }
    return responseString;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    EditText et=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    et.setText(result);
  }
}
```

As you can see I am setting the EditText box to the JSON which is returned. I pass a reference of the root view to my WebRequest class so that I can get hold of the EditText box.

Is there a better way of doing this? It does not seem very elegant. Perhaps a nice libary for web requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way works fine, and it is good to know how to write this. There are a couple of things you can do to improve this, and there is also a library you can use to *greatly* simplify your code.

### Option 1: Improve your code

First, you can use a `Callback` to set the text in the `EditText` in your `Activity`, instead:

Change these lines in `WebRequest`:

```
private View view;
public WebRequest(View v) {
   this.view = v;
}
```

to

```
public interface Callback {
    public void call(String result);
}
private Callback callback;
public WebRequest(Callback c) {
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

Then in `onPostExecute`, just call:

```
callback.call(result);
```

Now, when you start the web service, your call will look like this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        WebRequest wr=new WebRequest(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void call(String result) {
                ((EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText(result);
            }
        });
        wr.execute("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese?level=1");
    }
});
```

---

### Option 2: Use a library

If, however, you do want to use a **library**, I recommend my [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) library. Using this, you can simplify your code from this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myshowbutton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        WebRequest wr=new WebRequest(view.getRootView());
        wr.execute("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese?level=1");
    }
});
```

to:

```
$.with(this, R.id.myshowbutton).click(new Function() {
    @Override
    public void invoke($ d, Object... args) {
        $.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese?level=1").success(new Function() {
            @Override
            public void invoke($ d, Object... args) {
                $.with(MyActivity.this, R.id.editText).text(args[0].toString());
            }
        }));
    }
});
```

and you no longer need your `WebRequest` class.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with handing in a reference to a view into your AsyncTask is what happens when the Activity is destroyed and recreated for example in case of an orientation change (turning the device). In this case you can leak a reference to the Activity, which can get expensive memory-wise.

There are a couple of libraries around that try to help with this kind of problems. Maybe have a look at [RoboSpice](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) also.

Comment: This is good to know! I guess the Activity can also be destroyed because Android handles the memory management and can randomly destroy Activities if resources get low?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to decouple the `EditText` from your `WebRequest`, consider making a callback interface for your `MainActivity` to implement.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements WebRequestCallback {
    ...
    @Override
    public void handleStringResult(String result) {
        btn.setText(result);
    }
    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                WebRequest wr = new WebRequest(this);
                wr.execute("http://www.cheesejedi.com/rest_services/get_big_cheese?level=1");
            }
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

WebRequestCallback.java

```
public interface WebRequestCallback {
    public void handleStringResult(String result);
}
```

WebRequest.java

```
public class WebRequest extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private WebRequestCallback callback;

    public WebRequest(WebRequestCallback callback) {
       this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        callback.handleStringResult(result);
    }
}
```

Also, while I have not used it myself, I have heard good things about **[Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion/)** if you are looking for a more robust Android networking library.